# Loosing negative sign when extracting data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I extract temperature from a website into a dataframe. It looks like this:

```
           Temp      Prec
0     3 / -4 °C         -
1    1 / -17 °C         -
2   -7 / -18 °C         -
3     6 / -8 °C         -
4      8 / 1 °C         -
5      8 / 0 °C   1.3  mm
6      8 / 0 °C   7.0  mm
7     6 / -1 °C         -
8      4 / 0 °C   4.0  mm
9      5 / 2 °C  23.8  mm
10     6 / 1 °C         -
11    5 / -1 °C         -
12    4 / -1 °C         -
13     7 / 0 °C  10.6  mm
14     7 / 1 °C  29.7  mm
```

Then I use this code to extract the temperature in the format I want:

```
df2['Temp'] = df2['Temp'].str.extract('(\d+)') + 'C'
```

and I get this result:

```
   Temp      Prec
0    3C         -
1    1C         -
2    7C         -
3    6C         -
4    8C         -
5    8C   1.3  mm
6    8C   7.0  mm
7    6C         -
8    4C   4.0  mm
9    5C  23.8  mm
10   6C         -
11   5C         -
12   4C         -
13   7C  10.6  mm
14   7C  29.7  mm
```

I have lost the negative sign (like on row 2) when it's a temperature below zero. How can I keep the negative sign?

Comment: `.str.extract('(-?\d+)') + 'C'`

Comment: `(\d+)` just matches a sequence of digits. Do you know how to match a minus sign? Do you know how to make a token optional?

Comment: Ignatius, I appreciate, that is the help I wanted

Comment: "Then I use this code to extract the temperature in the format I want:" Please try to *think about* the problem before posting. Since you wrote the regex, I assume you understand what it means generally. You also have an observed problem: some part of the string isn't captured by the regex. It *should be clear* why not: `-` isn't one of the `\d` symbols. If you weren't sure about this, the next step would have been to read some documentation or a tutorial for regular expressions.

Comment: Karl, I searched an answer for the past two days, I'm a trader who use coding although I have no background in it. When I can't find the solution, in last resort, I post here knowing I'll get two different type of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without *regex*, go for [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and slice with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) :

```
df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.rsplit("/", n=1).str[-1]
```

And regarding the regex approach, you can include `°C` in the captured group :

```
df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.extract("(-?\d+\s*°C)", expand=False)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

      Temp     Prec
0    -4 °C        -
1   -17 °C        -
2   -18 °C        -
3    -8 °C        -
4     1 °C        -
5     0 °C   1.3 mm
6     0 °C   7.0 mm
8     0 °C   4.0 mm
9     2 °C  23.8 mm
10    1 °C        -
11   -1 °C        -
12   -1 °C        -
13    0 °C  10.6 mm
14    1 °C  29.7 mm
```